# Cloning a git-svn repository with svn metadata

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I've cloned my main repository with `git-svn clone svn://url/trunk --stdlayout`. Now I want to clone the repository, with the svn meta data. So that I'll be able to `git-svn rebase` it to the main server.

Note, I don't want to push commits between two `git-svn` clones, I simply want to add all the `git-svn` metadata to the newly cloned repository, so that the new clone will be able to communicate with the main subversion server as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's in the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). What you should do is:

```
git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*'
git fetch
```

to fetch the `svn` meta-branches. Then you'll be able to `git-svn rebase` without fetching everything from scratch.

---

Quoting from the docs:

> The initial git svn clone can be quite
>   time-consuming (especially for large
>   Subversion repositories). If multiple
>   people (or one person with multiple
>   machines) want to use git svn to
>   interact with the same Subversion
>   repository, you can do the initial git
>   svn clone to a repository on a server
>   and have each person clone that
>   repository with git clone:

```
# Do the initial import on a server
        ssh server "cd /pub && git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project
# Clone locally - make sure the refs/remotes/ space matches the server
        mkdir project
        cd project
        git init
        git remote add origin server:/pub/project
        git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*'
        git fetch
# Prevent fetch/pull from remote git server in the future,
# we only want to use git svn for future updates
        git config --remove-section remote.origin
# Create a local branch from one of the branches just fetched
        git checkout -b master FETCH_HEAD
# Initialize 'git svn' locally (be sure to use the same URL and -T/-b/-t options as were used on server)
        git svn init http://svn.example.com/project
# Pull the latest changes from Subversion
        git svn rebase
```

Comment: Question: How do you do this if you only want one subdirectory (e.g. `trunk`) but the checkout has everything?

Comment: `git svn rebase` hangs there. Is it supposed to be fast if the gitsvn repository is up to date with svn?

Answer (score 2):

### Super-fast simple copy-clone between remote machines

From the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> 'git clone' does not clone branches under the refs/remotes/ hierarchy or any 'git svn' metadata, or config. So repositories created and managed with using 'git svn' should use 'rsync' for cloning, if cloning is to be done at all.

A copy-clone on the same machine can simply be done using `cp -rp <src> <dst>`, and from a remote machine using `scp -rCp <src> <dst>`.

However, the remote case can be *very very* slow (10 minutes even on ethernet) because of the large number of tiny files it has to copy.

Using [`cpio`](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/cpio_directory.php) you can avoid this overhead, meaning (depending upon bandwidth) it just takes a few seconds (for a 100Mb git repo on a 50Mbit/s connection).

```
ssh -C <user>@<host> "cd <path to parent dir of repo>; \
find <repo directory name> -depth -print | cpio -oa" | cpio -imd
```

For example

```
ssh -C alex@myhost "cd ~alex/repos/; \
find WonderProject -depth -print | cpio -oa" | cpio -imd
```

results in a new git repo 'WonderProject' in the current working directory on the local machine.

---

*(note that the documentation I refer to almost denies the existence of the section @Elazar refers to, so I'm not discrediting @Elazar's excellent solution, but looking for a more concise memorable one)*

Comment: Aren't you better off using rsync instead of the cpio hack? Both should stream all files in bulk. Is there significant time difference?

Comment: possibly, possibly.  I'm not familiar with rsync.  Why is cpio a hack and rsync kosher?