# How do I continue pulling from subversion from a git clone which was not originally pointing to svn

Tags: git, git-svn

Given I have created a git repo on machine1 by pointing to svn with `git svn clone --trunk=http://foo/project`
And I keep pulling in new revisions from svn on machine1 with 'git svn rebase'
When I clone the git repo from machine1 to machine2
How do I repoint to svn my git repo on machine2 ???

So far I have done this:
Given I have repointed to svn with `git svn init --trunk=http://foo/project` on machine2
When I do 'git svn rebase' 
Then nothing happens, prompt just hangs.

When I do 'git svn fetch' 
Then git wants to reimport all of svn revisions as if it's brand new and that takes me 2 hours, but after that `git svn rebase` works fine.

When I do 'git svn fetch -r XXX' where XXX is the last svn revision id visible in last commit then I get some files from svn but after that `git svn rebase` just hangs and nothing happens.

I am looking for a procedure to repoint to a subversion trunk to keep pulling in new changes. I do not plan to commit back to SVN at all.

Any ideas?

My env setup:
git-svn version 1.7.9.5 (svn 1.6.17)
git version 1.7.9.5
on linux mint 13

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning a git-svn repository with svn metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339838/cloning-a-git-svn-repository-with-svn-metadata)

Comment: I have read that particular comment in docs but nothing clicked for me for the situation I found myself in. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

on machine2
`git svn init --trunk=http://foo/project`
Ready to fetch from Subversion?
Not yet. We need metadata for the relationship between git commit and svn revision.
Find out the last commit SHA1 that has svn revision `git show` or `git log -1`

And write SHA1  to `.git/refs/remotes/trunk`

`echo <SHA1> > .git/refs/remotes/trunk`

Now you can `git svn fetch`  (git will rebuild rev map on first try (5 minutes maybe)).

The above worked for me on a branch git repo used to pull the latest updates form svn.

Comment: I just had a similar problem. The more proper way to rewrite the ref is not manually, but through [git-update-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref). For example, instead of `echo <SHA1> > .git/refs/remotes/trunk`, one should do  `git update-ref --no-deref refs/remotes/trunk <SHA1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your local repository to have svn and the remote knowing that they are pointing to the same commits.

When you run (on machine2)

```
git svn init --trunk=http://foo/project
```

svn doesn't know that the repository it is pointing to is the same as the one you pulled from machine1.

To let git svn know that this is the case, you can use a prefix:

```
git svn init --prefix=origin/ --trunk=http://foo/project
```

(The trailing slash is important if you are going to use branches)

If you have already run the first init command, you can get the same result by editing your .git/config file to look like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    fetch = http://foo/project:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
```

note the **origin/** before trunk. If you don't want to edit the file manually, you can run:

```
git config --replace svn-remote.svn.fetch http://foo/project:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
```

Which will insert the line for you.

After doing this, you should be able to run `git svn fetch` and git will update your rev map.